# Elasticsearch: Add new field in big index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearchv7.6.

I have a big index with 10MLN of documents, I realized that I forgot a `field` with type `text` that I need in order to search on.

I added to the mapping this new field, with the `PUT MAPPING` api, and, while I can see the field in the mapping, I cannot do a search with that field.

My question is: why? Is there any way I can see the status of the new field indexing? what if something failed along the way?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a field is not sufficient, you need to send the document containing that field value, in order to search on that and you can't see the status of a single newly added field.

If you have a source doc in the older index form where you can fill the new field value than you can use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) which would be much faster.

If you are sending a document from an external sources like database etc, then you need to again reindex all data if you want all your 10 million docs to have the new field value.

Comment: so, adding a new field in the mapping doesn't index previous document that do contain that field?

Comment: @salvob, exactly :)